# NullpointerException in enum Logger

Tags: java, log4j

I have a class ValueRepository class and want to use a logger in it. The following code always throws a NullPointerException.

```
public enum ValueRepository {

INSTANCE;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValueRepository.class.getName());

private Map<String, Set<String>> key2value;
private Map value2key;

ValueRepository() {

    key2value = new HashMap();
    value2key = new HashMap();

    load("keyValue.txt");
}

public int size() {
    return key2value.size();
}

public boolean hasKey(String key) {
    return key2value.containsKey(key);
}

public boolean hasValue(String value) {
    return value2key.containsKey(value);
}

public Set<String> getValues(String key) {
    return key2value.get(key);
}

public String getKey(String value) {
    return (String) value2key.get(value);
}

private void load(String filePath) {

    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = IOUtils.fileReaderAsResource(filePath);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            LOGGER.info("test");
            line = line.trim();
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        LOGGER.error("Can't load the file: " + filePath);
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        // do nothing
    }
```

Shouldn't this work?

This question is very different from the link. It's specifically about why it doesn't work in logger in enum.

EDIT:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/congmi/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.6.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/congmi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.21/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.qe.repository.ValueRepository.load(ValueRepository.java:56)
    at com.qe.repository.ValueRepository.<init>(ValueRepository.java:26)
    at com.qe.repository.ValueRepository.<clinit>(ValueRepository.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValueRepository.class);`?

Comment: Both doesn't work.

Comment: Which package is `LoggerFactory` imported from?

Comment: import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: Looks like a possible duplicate to me. What's going on at `ValueRepository.java:56`?

Comment: It is a simple LOGGER.info("test");

Comment: Why haven't you posted the code that actually throws the error? Please include a [mcve].

Comment: LOGGER.info("test"); throws NULL pointer exception.

Comment: @user697911 *If* that is true, then `LoggerFactory.getLogger(..)` likely returns null (this is because the assignment is guaranteed first and once) - why might/can/is it returning null? Verify the hypothesis.

Comment: show us your main??

Comment: You're still calling `getName()`?

Comment: main added. it basically does nothing for testing.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, the same thing whether getName() is used or not.

Comment: **`SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.`** This is likely causing the `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` to return null. ***FIX THIS!!!*** You're currently telling SLF4J to bind with both Log4J 1.x and Log4J 2.x. You can't to that. Select a logging library and redirect everything else to it.

Comment: `INSTANCE` is initialized (by implicit constructor call) **before** `LOGGER` is initialized.
That means, you can't use `LOGGER` from within the constructor.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch. I guess that's the problem. But if I put the LOGGER statement before INSTANCE, it reports error "Can't resolve symbol INSTANCE". How to use logger in enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you designed your `ValueRepository` singleton as an `enum`
you got this initialization sequence of static constants:

1. `INSTANCE` (implicitly calling the constructor)
2. `LOGGER`

You need to change this initialization sequence to:

1. `LOGGER`
2. `INSTANCE`

You can't reach this sequence with `enum`, because the Java syntax insists
that the `enum` instances are the very first.

That means, you need to implement your singleton as a normal `class`, not as an `enum`.

```
public class ValueRepository {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValueRepository.class.getName());

    public static final ValueRepository INSTANCE = new ValueRepository();

    // remaining code unchanged

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** In your enum the static `LOGGER` variable is null until the constructor finishes. There are a few options for you.

1. Make the logger an instance variable (remove `static`),
2. Don't reference `LOGGER` during construction (throw an exception instead).
3. Load the data into a static field in a static initializer block, rather during the constructor.

**Long Answer:** In general, enum static fields will not resolve until the instances are built, whether or not you've got a singleton enum, or multiple enum entries.

That means any time you reference a `private static final` field that requires another piece of code running (aka - not a string or primitive) during the instance construction, it will fail with a `NullPointerException`.

See this [example in action here](http://tpcg.io/723Cul)

```
import java.util.Date;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
   final WierdEnum instance = WierdEnum.INSTANCE;
   instance.printStuff();
 }

 static enum WierdEnum {
     INSTANCE;

        private static final String test = "hello";
        private static final Date date = new Date();


     WierdEnum() {
       printStuff();
     }

     void printStuff() {
       System.out.println("Static string: " + test);
       System.out.println("Static date: " + date);
     }
 }
}
```

Resolves to:

```
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld
Hello World
Static string: hello
Static date: null
Static string: hello
Static date: Mon Apr 16 18:57:27 UTC 2018
```

The problem is that the class loading order is causing you to ending up with null class variables during the instance construction. This is a different order for an enum than for a class

I suspect you'd like to keep this an enum since you're using it as a singleton pattern and you probably have this pattern elsewhere in your code.  You have a few options:

**1.** Change the logger to an instance rather than class variable by removing `static`. We don't normally use an instance variable for a logger because it would have a logger for each instance of the object in the system.  In this case, there's only one!  So it's no problem.

```
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValueRepository.class);
```

**2.** OR Don't use the logger during construction. Instead of logging, throw a new exception if there is a problem reading the file.  I suspect that's preferable, since it doesn't look like you can recover from a failed file read.

```
} catch (IOException io) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Can't load the file: " + filePath, io);
}
```

**3.** Load the data into static fields in a static initializer block.

```
private static Map<String, Set<String>> key2value = new HashMap<>();
private static Map value2key = new HashMap();

static {
    load("keyValue.txt");
}

private static void load(String filePath) {
...
```